# Web application directories and data are lost during build and deploy of the application in tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I am developing a sample web application in spring tool suite. I find that during the builds in the Tomcat local host, I loose all the data that was stored prior to the build. Data include directories and their contents that were stored by the applicatin prior to the new build. I use the sample application to store pictures. The problem is all of the pictures are lost after a new build.  Is there a parameter that needs to be set to preserve the directories and the data. Is is this an expected process and that I need to backup all the application data prior to the build?

If I deploy on a cloud server using a .war file, will it behave the same way.

Please let me know if I need to post any files here.

Thanks
Balaji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you republish to Tomcat all new files form your workspace/project folder will be copied to the webapps folder, as well as all files in your webapps folder, which do not exist in your workspace, will be removed. If you upload files into f.e. webapps/YourProjectName/uploads/* directly, they will be removed because they do not exist in your workspace.

The best way is to separate your projects files (everything in your .war) from custom files like user data or uploads, by saving the the latter in a directory outside your webapps folder. Once you are republishing they are not going to be removed.

Otherwise, if you need something like 'example images' in your app to show to your customers (lets say they do not change that often) you can copy them into your workspace, so they will be republished every time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try moving my data folders outside of the project folders. Now I store them within the "webapp.Root". Thanks again for your reply.